# Python error with list

Tags: python, list

I need to replace all elements of the list camp by the respectives output values ​​of a function "counterPosition" that acts on each position of the list

```
camp = [[True, False, False, False, False, True],
         [False, False, False, False, False, True],
         [True, True, False, True, False, True],
         [True, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, True, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False]]


def counterPosition(x, y):
    bombs = 0
    for i in range(x-1, x+2):
        for j in range(y-1, y+2):
            if i<0 or j<0: continue
            elif camp[i][j] == True:
                bombs += 1
    return bombs

for x in range (len(camp)):
   for y in range (len(camp[x])):
       camp[x][y] = counterPosition(x,y)
print camp
```

Which gives:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: You try to access `camp[i][j]` when `i` can be `x+1` and `j` can be `y+1`.

Comment: This will not work well for you if you modify `camp` in place, which you are doing.

Comment: @Eric: I'm not sure what you mean. It's not going to cause an error (you can mutate the values of a `list` while iterating it, you just can't mutate the shape of the list itself, e.g. via inserting or deleting values). And it's certainly going to do _something_ (e.g., the first row will end up as `[2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2]`). The only question is whether that something is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `counterPosition` function. In particular:

```
for i in range(x-1, x+2):
    for j in range(y-1, y+2):
        …
        elif camp[i][j] == True:
```

You're passing this values of `x` ranging from `0` to `len(camp)-1`. Which means that `i` ranges from `-1` to `len(camp)-1+2`. So, for example, when you get to the last row, `x=5`, `i` will range from `-1` to `6`. But `camp[6]` is out of bounds. So you get an `IndexError`.

You'll have the same problem with `y` and `j`, of course.

So, how do you fix that? Well, it depends on what you're trying to do. But, given this line:

```
if i<0 or j<0: continue
```

I think what you want is to add this:

```
elif i>=len(camp) or j>=len(camp[i]): continue
```

Although really, it would be simpler to eliminate these outside the loop—e.g., `for i in range(max(x-1, 0), min(x+2, len(camp)):`

---

Meanwhile, I'm not sure what your program is trying to do, but it looks likesomething kind of Minesweeper-related, yes? If so, I don't think it's going to do what you want even after you fix this. As you replace the `True` and `False` values with counts, `camp[i][j] == True` can never be true for `i<=x and j<=y`. So, the end result is:

```
[[2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2],
 [2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2],
 [3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
 [1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2],
 [1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2],
 [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]]
```

When I think you may have wanted this:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3],
 [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2],
 [3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

That's the number of adjacent bombs at even given square. To get the latter, either iterate over or modify a copy of `camp`, instead of doing both to the same `list`. For example:

```
newcamp = copy.deepcopy(camp)
for x in range (len(camp)):
   for y in range (len(camp[x])):
       newcamp[x][y] = counterPosition(x,y)
print newcamp
```

Or just:

```
camp = [[counterPosition(x, y) for y in range(len(camp[x]))] 
        for x in range(len(camp))]
print camp
```

(Although really, I'd give them different names, like `bombcamp` and `flagcamp` or something…)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly that!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to store this data is to use a set:

```
bombs = {
    (i, j) for i, row in enumerate(camp)
           for j, is_bomb in enumerate(row)
           if is_bomb
}
```

And then, instead of `camp[i][j] == True`, do `(i, j) in bombs`